# Comparing druid and pipelinedb

Tags: performance, memory, aggregate, benchmarking, scalability

I have been working on aggregation of streaming data, I found 2 tools to achieve the same. They are druid and pipelinedb. I have understood the implementation and architecture of the both. But couldn't figure out a way to benchmark these two. Is there any existing benchmark test that has been done? Or if I want to do a benchmarking of my own apart from the speed and scalability what are all the factors that I need to consider. Any ideas, links and help would be really appreciable. Also do share your own experience with pipelinedb and druid

Thanks

Comment: Did you find anything? Looking for the same thing. What did you go with in the end and why?

Answer (score 0):

UPD:

After reading PipelineDB pages, I only wonder why do you need to compare such different things?

Druid is quite complex to install and maintain, it requires several external dependencies (such as zookeeper and hdfs/amazon, which must be maintained too).

And for that price you buy the key features of druid: **column-oriented** and **distributed** storage and processing. That also implies horizontal scalabitily out-of-the box, and it is completely automatic, you don't have even to think about it.

So if you don't need its distributed nature, I'd say you don't need druid at all.

FIRST VERSION:

I have no experience with pipelinedb (what is it? google shows nothing, pls share some link), but I have much experience with druid. So I would consider (apart from [query] speed and scalability):

1. ingesting performance (how many rows per sec/min/hour/... can be
   inserted?)
2. RAM consumption of ingesting (how much RAM it needs to ingest with target speed?)
3. compression level (how many disk space needs one
       hour/day/month/... of data?)
4. fault-tolerance (what happens when some
       of the components fail? it is critical for my business?)
5. Caching (just keep in mind)

Comment: what google are you using ? pipelinedb is pretty well referenced. https://www.pipelinedb.com/

Comment: just yesterday it showed tons of "buy-this-domain" pages